# Netsuite Tribe Hr Integration

Tags: netsuite

I am integrating netsuite with tribehr. I am trying to access the Tribehr system with restlet. Getting two errors:

1) SSS_INVALID_URL: Connection closed because of an invalid URL. The URL must be a fully qualified HTTP or HTTPS URL if it is referencing a non-NetSuite resource. The URL cannot contain white space.

2) NetSuite received a non-200 response code: 404: .

1st error getting when  i m calling tribehr thr following code:

```
var url = 'https://[n*******l@gmail.com]:[a19c6cc1************363d5a33be98efc]@*******.mytribehr.com/users.json';
   var res = url.replace(/%20/g, '');
   var headers = new Array();
   headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json';
   headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

   var response = nlapiRequestURL(res, null, headers); //calling the service
```

2nd error when trying to use javascript function to remove white spaces and append credentials to url component..

```
var parameter1 = "https://*******.mytribehr.com/X-API-Version:2.0.0/users/98.json?";

   parameter1 += "&uname=" +encodeURIComponent(uname);
   parameter1 += "&key=" +encodeURIComponent(key);


   var headers = new Array();
   headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json';
   headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

   var response = nlapiRequestURL(parameter1, null, headers); //calling the service
```

*Note : Both the external urls i am trying to access are working since I have tested them.

Do let me possible solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Glad

Answer (score 1):

So you tried using something like Postman for Chrome or HttpRequester for Firefox to double check all your headers and URLs? Since that checks out, you can try using the NetSuite debugger URL to step through your code and verify each step.